# using js operator ... to pass data into redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i want to pass a nested object into redux reducer, i know i have to use the ... operator to make a deep copy. But i can not find out how to pass/copy the 'comments' array and the '_user' objet nested into each element of the 'comments' array.

```
{
"mess": "",
"article": {
    "_id": "5faba634513b091effd8c37f",
    "article": "intoheadLifestyle",
    "likeArt": 0,
    "dislikeArt": 0,
    "comments": [
        {
            "_id": "5faba635513b091effd8c381",
            "commentId": {
                "_id": "5faba634513b091effd8c380",
                "comment": "finish for today, all is working as expected, even better .....",
                "like": 0,
                "dislike": 0,
                "_user": {
                    "_id": "5fa93d08533de7437c77a5a0",
                    "username": "jerome",
                    "password": "$2b$10$is66cqM5K5ZE/z7T34a54e0TNXSrdVZIx7jF5sqkZQ1gAwOplt4Si",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "createdAt": "2020-11-11T08:52:04.960Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "5faba64b513b091effd8c383",
            "commentId": {
                "_id": "5faba64a513b091effd8c382",
                "comment": "another coent ca c bien coool",
                "like": 0,
                "dislike": 0,
                "_user": {
                    "_id": "5fa93d08533de7437c77a5a0",
                    "username": "jerome",
                    "password": "$2b$10$is66cqM5K5ZE/z7T34a54e0TNXSrdVZIx7jF5sqkZQ1gAwOplt4Si",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "createdAt": "2020-11-11T08:52:26.995Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 2
}
```

}

this object is comming from "res.payload.data", so i tryied to do that

```
let datas = {...res.payload.data,
                  article: {...res.payload.data.article,
                           // then i don t know for the 'comments' array ..???
                           // and i am lost for the '_user' object into each element of the array...
```

Thank you if someone have an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant spreading the array `[...value]`

```
let datas = {
  ...res.payload.data,
  article: {
    ...res.payload.data.article,
    comments: [...res.payload.data.article.comments],
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, i understand how to pass the comments[], Thank you.

But how to pass the '_user' object which is into each element of the 'comments' array, it needs to be spread (i don't know if we say it like this.) as well...